# Sqlalchemy model name conflicts with automap

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have large database, which has tables "menu_category"(model menu.Category) and "kitchen_category"(model kitchen.Category).

Model "ProductDetail" has foreign keys to both this models:

```
from kitchen import Category as KitchenCategory

class Detail(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'menu_productdetail'

    category_id = Column(ForeignKey('menu_category.id'))
    category = relationship(Category)

    kitchen_category_id = Column(ForeignKey('kitchen_category.id'))
    kitchen_category = relationship(KitchenCategory)
```

This code produces error:

> reverse_property 'category' on relationship Category.detail_collection references relationship Detail.category, which does not reference mapper Mapper|Category|kitchen_category

But if I rename model kitchen.Category to kitchen.KitchenCategory:

```
from kitchen import KitchenCategory
class Detail(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'menu_productdetail'

    category_id = Column(ForeignKey('menu_category.id'))
    category = relationship(Category, backref='details')
    brands = relationship("Brand", secondary=brand_product_detail_association_table)

    kitchen_category_id = Column(ForeignKey('kitchen_category.id'))
    kitchen_category = relationship(KitchenCategory, backref='details')
```

then it works well. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I use automap to reflect database into models

Comment: Well, for one, you have a `Category` model in both examples, which you appear to be renaming to each other. The error message is saying `Category.detail_collection` (from the `kitchen_category` table) has a backref to `Detail.category`, but it doesn't refer to `Category` (`kitchen_category`) but instead it refers to `Category` (`menu_category`). Please don't rename different models to the same name.

Comment: I use the same **class name** 'Category' in different domains ('menu' and 'kitchen'). So why can't I do this? Even if I clearly point relationship to the right foreign key I get this error

`category = relationship(Category, foreign_keys=category_id)
kitchen_category = relationship(KitchenCategory, foreign_keys=kitchen_category_id)
`
It's just same class name, not table name, so sqlalchemy behavior is unobvious for me

Comment: Because it's not the configuration on `Detail` that's wrong; it's `Category` (whichever one has `detail_collection`).